# how to add a dot (.) inside a field name?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

When I run this command :

```
db.runCommand( 

  {
    aggregate:"myColl",
    pipeline:[
      {
        $group:{
          _id:{os_name:"$os_name",os_version:"$os_version"},
          "events.login":{$sum:"$events.login"},
          count:{$sum:NumberInt(1)}}
      }
    ],
    cursor:{}
  }

 )
```

I receive the error:

> The field name 'events.login' cannot contain '.'

How can i do to keep the '.' in the returned field name (ie: `events.login`)

Comment: You need to add one more `$project` stage to do this. `$group` stage does not allow to `.` dot in field names.

Comment: @Ashh thanks i don't understand, what is $project ? how to add it ?

Comment: [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) is another stage like `$group`.

Comment: @Ashh I just try with project, it's didn't change anything :( or I misunderstand how to use it ...

Comment: Could you show the sample documents and the output

Comment: @Ashh same document as before, i just add in it $project:{"events.login":1} output is same, The field name 'events.login' cannot contain '.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quiet clear what you're trying to do, So look at these :

**Error :**

> The field name 'events.login' cannot contain '.'

It's because as in `$group` stage when it creates a new field on each document for a given name, You'll not be able to create it like this : `"events.login"` means cannot create a sub-doc it has to be an object to a top level field `events` basically you can not use `.` notation, So to make it work you need to have one more stage like this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: { os_name: "$os_name", os_version: "$os_version" },
        "events": { $sum: "$events.login" },
        count: { $sum: NumberInt(1) }
    }
}, { $addFields: { 'events.login': '$events' } }])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cz9giasDUYF)

If in a case you need to update `login` field inside `events` field & to retain all other fields inside `events`, try below query which would get last document in iteration of each `_id` (this will last document inserted to DB on that `_id` criteria) & append `login` to it :

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: { os_name: "$os_name", os_version: "$os_version" },
        "login": { $sum: "$events.login" }, 'events': { $last: '$events' },
        count: { $sum: NumberInt(1) }
    }
}, { $addFields: { 'events.login': '$login' } }, { $project: { login: 0 } }])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tCMayPsCs7G)